# Why does saveInBackgroundWithBlock only work *once* in my Parse-enabled class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a class with this code which gets called a few times per minute on average, and only runs on the main thread:

```
        PFObject* eventObj = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"AdminConsoleEvent"];
        eventObj[kACParseEventName] = event;
        eventObj[kACParseEventUrgency] = urgency;
        if( param1 )
            eventObj[kACParseEventParam1] = param1;
        eventObj[kACParseEventPointerToAdminConsole] = self.adminConsole;
        === [eventObj saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
           +++ if( !succeeded ) {
                //here
            }
        }];
```

If I put a breakpoint where === is, I see that every time eventObj is how I expect... a non-nil object with valid information on it.

If I put a breakpoint where +++ is, then I see that it gets hit exactly only once -- the first time this code is called. If I look on the Parse data browser (online), sure enough, only the first object gets saved (immediately)! The rest never show up.

Why the heck isn't the block (+++) ever running for subsequent calls? Why aren't the other objects being saved?

Comment: Can you log `error` on the +++ line?

Comment: The block never gets called. So there's no error, nothing at all

Comment: What happens if you step inside `saveInBackgroundWithBlock`? The method even calls your server? If does, the return is what you expected? I suspect that your block isn't being called from there for some reason.

Comment: I mean on the first call that seems to work. Maybe there's a clue there.

Comment: @danh error is nil on the first call -- suceeded is true.

Comment: @KioCoan I don't understand what you mean. SaveInBackgroundWithBlock is an internal parse method that I can only see assembly language for in lldb. It returns void.

Comment: Strange.  You should be able to make any terrible mistake and parse should always call the completion block.  So in that sense, whether or not you have a bug, parse has a bug.  The next debug thing I'd try to to make a new class with no columns.  Just try to save two of those in a row.  That will work, right?  So then, let's step by step add columns, step by step add code leading up to the save.  With each step/test make it more resemble your current code.  At some point its going to stop working, right?  Then we'll know.

Comment: in case it helps, if I change `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` to just `save:NSError**` (so that it is synchronous), then it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK this fixed it...

```
[PFObject saveAllInBackground:@[eventObj, self.adminConsole] block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
```

I assume that this is because there was a circular reference: self.adminConsole had a reference being added to it for eventObj, and eventObj had a reference being added to it for self.adminConsole. For whatever reason, that breaks Parse for me if I use saveInBackground directly on the objects.

Comment: Thanks, this just helped me out greatly. Feel like some kind of error should be given though!